# Background Elements Shifting on Navigation Mouseover

Tags: wss-3.0, navigation, page-layout

On Google Chrome - When I mouse over the navigation bar items on Sharepoint pages, it causes page elements in the background to shift up the page moving the mouse off the navigation element and causing a flickering effect.

This is an unmodified page, I am not developing a web part so no changes made, it occurs in my Team Discussion page as well as my Document Library.

When I mouse over an item (circled in red) it causes the area (circled in Fushia) to move up to where the red arrow indicates.
[image: The Bug]

*Currently uploading a short video*

[Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eLvESb-54I&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Did you try this in other PC's, what browser are you using ?

Comment: This is Chrome specific, I'm getting the same error on other computers on the network.

Comment: And what if you try in IE.. same behaviour ?

Comment: @Arsalan It's Chrome specific, it only happens in Google Chrome.

Comment: Try getting latest version of Chrome and test, if that doesn't fix the issue... Try checking what css changes are made when you hover with Chrome Inspect element option!